# Why does PowerShell not sort strings correctly?

Tags: string, powershell, sorting

I want to sort a list of strings in powershell, but when I attempt to do so I get a result that is not sorted at all.

```
  PS C:\Windows\system32> "bbb", "aaa", "ccc" | sort
    bbb
    ccc
    aaa
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Try to be sure to use the good CmdLet:

```
"bbb", "aaa", "ccc" | Sort-Object
```

Works for me:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Then try to verify your alias:

```
PS> Get-Alias sort

CommandType     Name                                       Version    Source
-----------     ----                                       -------    ------
Alias           sort -> Sort-Object
```

Comment: `sort` is an alias for `sort-object` so I get the same result.